# From String to map[string]interface{} golang

Tags: string, go

I would like to turn this string into map [string] interface {}:

```
result="map[Value1:TestWS Value2:00060636 Value3:TestWS Value4:PIPPO Value5:TestWS]"
```

the same string printed through the JSON

```
"result=\"map[COD_DIPENDENTE:00060636 MATRICOLA:TestWS COGNOME:CAPPONI NOMEmy:TestWS COGNOMEmy:TestWS]\"\n"
```

I understand that it is a particular string. In reality it derives from a map [string] interface {}, but this has gone through an encryption and a decryption and the result is this.

The "result" is not fundamental.

advice??

Comment: This string seems like from the output of log on console which you have assigned to result. Try to parse it there where you are creating this string. Are you parsing json to create this string.

Comment: Space-delimited string values may be impossible to parse - what happens if the key or value contains a space?

Comment: Can you share the code that created this?

Comment: The map part isn't a golang map at all, it's a string that you could parse into a `map[string]interface{}` variable. The latter is just a string, it's not a JSON representation of a map. A map should be represented as a JSON object

Comment: Yes it is true, maybe I was a little inaccurate. I found the solution Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @bed how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package stackoverflow

import "strings"

func StrToMap(in string) map[string]interface{} {
    res := make(map[string]interface{})
    array := strings.Split(in, " ")
    temp := make([]string, 2)
    for _, val := range array {
        temp = strings.Split(string(val), ":")
        res[temp[0]] = temp[1]
    }
    return res
}
```

the above function returns an map of string to strings. It also doesn't handle the `map[]` part, which you can remove by either splitting the string before passing it or simply looking into why it gets printed that way(in the original code).

Comment: Thanks man, if I delete the string part out of map [] it works.